# download.file inserts an extra CR after each CRLF

Tags: r

```
# 2.3 MB file
download.file("http://www.nzta.govt.nz/resources/crash-analysis-system-data/docs/crash-data-2014.csv"
              , "temp.csv")

# Blank lines cause fread to fail
data.table::fread("temp.csv")

# Empty data.table (0 rows) of 29 cols: TLA NAME,CRASH ROAD,CRASH DIST,CRASH DIRN,INTSN,SIDE ROAD...
```

Opening the file in Notepad++ shows that an extra CR character has been inserted after every CRLF pair of characters.  This does not happen if I download the file through a browser (Chrome).

What's going on?

I'm on Windows XP, unfortunately.

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_New Zealand.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_New Zealand.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_New Zealand.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                         LC_TIME=English_New Zealand.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] data.table_1.9.2 plyr_1.8.1       Rcpp_0.11.3      reshape2_1.4     stringr_0.6.2    tools_3.1.1
```

Comment: Ugh, fixed it by trying the obscure `mode` argument.

Comment: "obscure"? `help("download.file")` is an arcane command?

Comment: Obscure because you wouldn't bother with `mode` unless you somehow already know that the original file isn't corrupt, that line ending characters are different between UNIX and windows, that FTP tries to automatically correct them, and that FTP guesses wrongly in the case of a text file stored in binary format on a UNIX server being transferred to a Windows machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
download.file(url, destfile, mode = "wb")
```